# MongoDB: After implementing TTL, no longer have permissions to query DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using  version 2.6.12 of Mongo

I used the following to implement a TTL on a collection:

```
db.collectionname.createIndex( { "createdDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 8208000 } )
```

Everything after 90 days should expire from the collection.

When I attempt to do a find

```
db.system.collectionname .find( { createdDate: { $lt: ISODate("2018-04-01") } } ).count()
```

I get the following error message

```
"ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on db to execute command { count: \"system.scanObjects\", query: { createdDate: { $lt: new Date(1538352000000) } }, fields: {} }",
    "code" : 13
```

I not showing the collection name when i attempt to find the permissions

```
db.getRole( "readWrite", { showPrivileges: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is you've added `system` into your query when it shouldn't be there. Try the following:

```
db.collectionname .find( { createdDate: { $lt: ISODate("2018-04-01") } } ).count()
```

[System collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/system-collections/) are special internal collections that you shouldn't be modifying.